# scala foreach loop return list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am a newbie to scala (and functional programming, basically). I am trying to loop over a list of rows (can think as strings), where each string will be passed to a different scala method, where I am doing some manipulation on the input string and then return a string to the for-loop.

below is not the working code, but this is what I am expecting to work.

```
     val input_list = spark.read
          .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
          .option("sheetName" , "SchemaInfo")
          .option("useHeader", "true")
          .schema(profilerSchema)
          .load(path)  // this is spark dataframe, which has rows.

 val columnNames : List[String] = new List("Hello" , "world");

         var outputList = new ListBuffer[String]();

        // Here i am iterating the input_list where i pass each ele to getString() method where  
        // it returns the final string which i want to add to outputList. 

         input_list.foreach(i => {
                val res: String = getString(row, columnNames)
                 outputList += res;
               }));


         def getString(row: Row, schemaNames: List[String]) : String  = {

        // some implementation where it returns a string.
        }
```

Below is the error message I am getting (discard the line number. its getting at the foreach loop.).

```
Error:(57, 14) overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])Unit <and>
  (f: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Unit)Unit
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Row => scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String])
    excel_df.foreach{row => (jsonStrList += convertRowToJSON(row, columnNames))};
```

I am having a hard time writing the logic. any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working right now? What error messages are you getting? Or if you're not getting any, what's the output you see versus what you expect? Also, `getString` asks for a `Row` but you pass it a `String`, I assume it should take `String` in this example?

Comment: HI Ethan, my bad. i had updated the question with the error message. thanks

Comment: We don't recommend use of var in Scala. Especially if you are trying to do functional programming. There are no mutations in FP. Please use a For/yield or it seems like even a .map would suffice in this case

Comment: You have an extra ending parentheses in the expression where you call foreach. However, I don't think that's why your code is failing. Your real problem is that the input variable to your anonymous function, `i`, is never used in your function. You are either omitting some important code, or else something else is going on. For starters, can you tell us the type for `input_list`? It would help us debug your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input_list.foreach(i => {
      val res: String = getString(row, columnNames)
       outputList += res;
     });
```

Your function inside the foreach method returns the outputList value. If you look at the signature, the return value should be Unit - which means the method doesn't return a value. It assumes you do some calculation that doesn't return anything.

You should use map instead of foreach. You don't need foreach and the outputList variable.

```
input_list.map(row => {
       // Logic to return the item that you want to compute
     })
     .toList()
```

You have to shift your way of thinking from an imperative style where you declare a collection and then loop through the items of another collection and add the result of your calculations to the first collection to a functional style that uses the map/filter methods.

Example:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
// filter gives you the list of even numbers between 1 and 10
.filter(i => i % 2 == 0) 
// This gives you the squares of the even numbers between 1 and 10
.map(i => i * i)
// This gives the doubles of the squares of the even numbers
.map(i => i * 2)
```

You can also do this:

```
val evenNumbers = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
// filter gives you the list of even numbers between 1 and 10
.filter(i => i % 2 == 0) 

val squares= evenNumbers
// This gives you the squares of the even numbers between 1 and 10
.map(i => i * i)

val doubleSquares = squares
// This gives the doubles of the squares of the even numbers
.map(i => i * 2)

// this will return a tuple with lists when it's the last statement in a function or method.
(squares, doubleSquares)
```

As you can see there are no ListBuffer objects declared. The example is a bit contrived, you could combine the last two maps into one but I wanted to prove a point. You can do other operations, you can group by items, sort them and so on.

You need to read more about scala and FP in general. This is a good introduction: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/introduction.html and this: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/passing-functions-around.html.

You can also trying things here inside the browser: https://scastie.scala-lang.org.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in this case, using vars and mutable collections is a straight up error, since the code is being run with spark.

Comment: In case costa's solution isn't clear enough, here is what the code should look like: `val outputList = input_list.map(row => getString(row, columnNames)).toList()`. Something like that. I'm not sure if this code snippet compiles because I don't know the type of `input_list`, but oh well. `outputList` will be a List[String].

Comment: thanks @Allen. it working. as I am working on a dataframe, I need to use the collect() method and then make it to list by using toList.

val jsonStrList : List[String] = excel_df.map(row => convertRowToJSON(row, columnNames)).collect().toList

Comment: @Costa, what do you meant by, I don't need an outputList variable ? As from the inputList, once I get the output, I need to save it to a list right? Am I thinking wrong ?

Comment: @marc: In the FP style of programming you don't do that. You could store your temporary results in variables declared with val (not var). Think of the whole thing as a pipeline. You start with some initial list, you apply it transformations(i.e functions) and you get another list as a result, then you transform that list if you need to and so on. Scala is very good at retaining the original collection type, i.e. if you start with a List and you apply filter and map you end up with a list.

Comment: As for an example, I updated the answer to include it. I could not get the formatting in these comments working properly.

Comment: got it Costa. really appreciate you for going extra mile in explaining the things. Kudos.:)

Comment: @marc. Np - keep also in mind what Ethan said. Spark might evaluate a dataframe on different nodes. You have to be extra careful about how you write these queries.